# Caching absolute urls vs local urls

Tags: caching

Is there any benefit to linking to images that are based on your url locally 

*e.g. /images/myimage.jpg* rather than *http://www.google.co.uk/images/myimage.jpg* 
In terms of performance benefits or is it all added to the same pot when executed by the browser?

Cheers
Ian

Answer (score 1):

No performance difference I'd say. Use relative URLs so that:

1. When changing from your localhost to an external server, it doesn't break your links.
2. It's marginally smaller. (hey, every byte counts right?)

**In other words, for your convenience, use relative paths.**